# What happens when an SD card gets connected to a Linux computer

Tags: filesystems, udev, devices, block-device, sd-card

I'm still quite confused as to how this works exactly.

When we connect an SD card to a computer running a Linux system, this is my understanding (Please feel free to correct on the smallest of details which are incorrect ) :

Linux identifies the device as an SD card by an identifier stored on the SD card. Along with this identifier, there is an SD card controller which takes care about reading and writing from and to the card.

In Linux, the SD card shows up as a block device in `/dev` . An SD card driver will then get loaded into the kernel and connected to use with the device file. This SD card driver takes care about writing and reading to and from the SD card controller on the SD card.

Now, when we wish to format the SD card and use a particular filesystem for it such as FAT32, where does this filesystem controller code come into all this? Does it get written onto the card, or just on the Linux computer? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

FAT is a format, similar to, say, JPEG, in that it defines the structure of data. That structure isn't dependent on the device used to write it (so it's not "just on the linux computer"), and a filesystem identifier and address table are written to the formatted partition so that the fs can be used, so you were right in saying that data gets written to the card. Kernel-level reading of the sd card handles decoding bits using a specific protocol (sd or spi), and it is up to software packages (drivers) to make sense of the raw data (by reading the address table). Your question was a bit unclear but in summary: kernel modules can be used to read raw data from an sd, and software drivers structure it in a human readable way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So a filesystem identifier gets written to the partition on the card, but where does the filesystem "driver" come into all this in order to tell the SD card controller how to structure the data?